# laravel 8 API : how pass username with Auth as user_id value for store post

Tags: laravel, api, validation, jwt

I'm building an API with Laravel 8.

I have a `posts` table with these columns:

```
id
category_id
user_id
title
body
picture
study_time
likes
tags
```

When a user is logged in as an author or admin, they can add a new post.

and for `user_id` field, I want to make that field guarded, I want to show username with  `JWTAuth::user()->username` and register it for user_id column .. so no one can enter any value for it

edit :
when i send request it gives me this error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into posts`

this is my store method in PostController:

```php
$data = $request->all();
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'category_id' => 'required',
    'title' => 'required|max:100|unique:categories',
    'body' => 'required',
    'picture' => 'required',
    'study_time' => 'required',
    'tags' => 'null|string',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'Validation Error']);
}

$tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

$post = Post::create($data);
$post->tag($tags);

return response()->json([
 'username' => JWTAuth::user()->username,
 'post' => $post
], 201);
```

Comment: first of all I suggest you use request and resources respect to single responsibilty (S of SOLID) and clean code. then I have a question: whta did you mean actually? you cand write id after JWTAuth::user() to get user_id. what's problem?

Comment: as you see , with this controller when i send request in postman .. it says : ` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this after $data=$request->all():

```
$data['user_id'] = JWTAuth::user()->id;
```

or you can use this instead (if you define posts in user model):

```
JWTAuth::user()->posts()->create($data);
```

Comment: thank you but why i get this error ? `ErrorException: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object`

Comment: Maybe you don't have any field as username in user model. Chech user_name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$request->user()` to get the current user.

Comment: i edited my question.. please check it and see my error

Answer (score 0):

```
$post = Post::create($data);
$post->tag($tags);
$post->username => JWTAuth::user()->username

return response()->json([
    'post' => $post
], 201);
```

Comment: my problem is this error when i send request : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into posts`

not json

Comment: it's because the "user_id" field is required but you didn't pass it in when created the Post object. After you validate all the data, set `$data['user_id'] = JWTAuth::id()`, and then do `Post::create($data)`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.